# Dealing with cross-cutting concerns

Tags: oop, architecture, cross-cutting-concerns

In programming, cross-cutting concerns are a common concern (For lack of better terms).

For example, if you are modelling an aircraft and all its composite parts in classes, various devices will depend on the same type of part. E.g. fuel tank, water tank, etc.

I have the same issue to deal with in my design. Apart from AOP, what strategies are there to deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: I've been doing oop for 15+ years, and I have no idea what you're getting at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, AOP is conceived to deal, by definition, with cross-cutting concerns. The answer to your question is, therefore, AOP. You don't need anything else apart from AOP. Why would you?